# How would I use Moq for a FindWhere method?

Tags: c#, moq

I'm using Moq with a MVC3 project and EF (code first). I currently have a Mock setup like so

```
    (In Repository)
    IQueryable<T> FindAll();
    IQueryable<T> FindWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    (In Mock tests)

    _providerRepository.Setup(mr => mr.FindById(
    It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int i) => _providerData.Where(
    x => x.Id == i).Single());
```

which works fine, my question is what would a sample Mock for FindWhere(..  look like?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample is incomplete, but I'm assuming that `_providerRepository` is of type `IRepository<Provider>`. I think this should work (basically the same way as your other example):

```
_providerRepository
   .Setup(mr => mr.FindWhere(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Provider,bool>>>()))
   .Returns(expression => _providerData.AsQueryable().Where(expression))
```

You may or may not need the `AsQueryable`.